# Is it possible to publish to a channel group in pubnub ? (Stream controller)

Tags: pubnub

Is it possible in pubnub that one can publish to a channel group and receive the message to all channels that were added to channel group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Publishing to a Channel Group

Publishing to a channel group or mulitiple channels is not a supported at this time. Using PubNub BLOCKS, you will be able to implement a pattern that would do this in a scalable fashion.

The question is...

*Why not have all the clients subscribe to the same channel and publish the message once to that channel?*

I'm sure you have a valid requirement here but would like to understand the details of it first.

Comment: Thank you! I've to send push notifications to around 10L user's individual channels daily, if I send this one by one, this process will take huge time. Is there any way through which I can send it in minimal time?